# Remove old error log files

Tags: unix

`error_log` files in `/var/log/httpd/` are consuming a lot of disk space.

There are `error_log.1`, `error_log.2` files as well. I will like to delete the old files automatically and keep only the current one.

Comment: Remember that http://serverfault.com exists for such questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to investigate [logrotate](http://www.google.fr/search?q=logrotate).

Comment: In this case, it seems as though the logs are already being rotated -- they should investigate what their current log rotation strategy is, and modify it.